# Read files from Windows shared folder using Airflow on remote server?

Tags: windows, airflow, etl, remote-server, shared-directory

What is the best method for reading files from a Windows shared folder using a DAG on a remote Apache Airflow server?

My current process needs to be executed a remote Airflow server, but it needs to read and write files (which the client and my process update) that are stored on a shared net Windows folder.

- Airflow is installed on remote Linux server (same network)
- Windows folders are just standard UNC paths where people have access based on their NT ID. These users are saving files which I need to retrieve.
- The files formats are .csv, .xls and .xlsx, which I plan to convert as Dataframes in my Airflow process
- Best if I can save my user and password within an Airflow connection to access it with a conn_id

Comment: Hi - what's stopping you connecting to the Windows shares from your Linux server?

Comment: I don't know how to do that (I'm pretty new to Airflow and working on a remote server)

Comment: You probably need to talk to whoever administers your linux server